# Scikit-learn does not work with string value on KNN

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

I'm using Scikit learn to do a K-Nearest Neigbour Classification:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

model=KNeighborsClassifier() 
model.fit(train_input,train_labels)
```

If I print my data:

```
print("train_input:")
print(train_input.iloc[0])
print("\n")
print("train_labels:")
print(train_labels.iloc[0])
```

I get this:

```
train_input:
PassengerId                          1
Pclass                               3
Name           Braund, Mr. Owen Harris
Sex                               male
Age                                 22
SibSp                                1
Parch                                0
Ticket                       A/5 21171
Fare                              7.25
Cabin                              NaN
Embarked                             S
Name: 0, dtype: object


train_labels:
0
```

The code fails with this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-1f18eec1e602> in <module>()
     63 
     64 model=KNeighborsClassifier()
---> 65 model.fit(train_input,train_labels)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Q'
```

So, does the KNN algorithm not work with `String` values?

How can I modify my data such that it fits the KNN implementation in Scikit-Learn?

Comment: The problem is not of Scikit Learn, it is in your understanding/formulation. A kNN measures how "close" are two data points in the feature space. In order for it to work properly you have to encode features so that you can measure difference/distance. E.g. from male to female the difference is in the semantics, not in the string representation. Thus, if you encode "male=0"  and "female=1" you can start measuring differences. Same applies to every other "feature".

Comment: Not just KNN, all scikit estimators only work on numerical data.

Answer (score 5):

For nominal `String` features, consider one hot encoding: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html.

For ordinal `String` features, consider label encoding (with a sensible ordering based on your understanding of the feature): http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html.

Comment: If I were to predict football matches, which would you recommend for team names

Comment: It doesn't matter for a dataset that size. I'd recommend LabelEncoder, it simply maps the names to numbers. The one hot encoder would work too, but it's unnecessary. It generally would also take much more memory, but that wouldn't matter for something as small as NFL team name data.